# How to use multiple source files for a single program with emu8086?

Tags: assembly, include, x86-16, emu8086

I'm writing a project in assembly 8086 and it's getting pretty huge.  I would like to divide it in smaller parts, to make it run faster.  I want to split my source code into multiple separate files, but still have them be part of the same program.

I'm using Emu8086.

I suppose in C it would look a little bit like this.

```
#include "sample file"
```

Comment: In C you would split the source code into separate files and compile them individually into object files. You'd then link the object files into a single executable. You can do the same thing in assembly.

Comment: Splitting it into multiple files wouldn't make it run faster. It makes the program more manageable. I have never really used EMU8086 for a project, but I wasn't aware it allowed multiple object files for a project (but I don't know 100%). I do know is that it has an `include` directive that allows you to include another file that may contain source code and macros. EMU8086 is rather restrictive compared to a modern conventional assembler/linker.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Any idea how to perform this?

Comment: I fixed your question to ask what you apparently wanted to know, instead of asking for multiple programs that call each other (multi-processing with remote procedure calls?).  Any reason you are sticking to emu8086 for this, rather than using a modern assembler like YASM or NASM to make a 16bit binary that you could run in DOSBOX or something?  That would let you build separate object files separately, and link at the end, if you wanted.  It would also make it easy to write some parts in C, instead of the whole thing in ASM.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use other assemblers or even completely different languages. It's a university project. Whole subject is about this specific ASM.

Answer (score 4):

In emu8086 the directive `include "..."` works in exactly the same way as `#include "..."` in C. The content of the (text-)file is inserted as if it was typed in there. One caveat: The text file must be DOS formatted, i.e. the new lines have to be coded with the two characters 0x0D and 0x0A.

Comment: Note - the conventional suffix for .asm include files is .inc.